# Show that $U_{22}$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Is there a quick way to show that $U_{22}$ is cyclic?

I know that $|U_{22}|=10$ and I know that I could go through and find an element of order $10$ but is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find $\mathbb{Z}_{22}^*$, the units of $\mathbb{Z}_{22}$. You know that $\mathbb{Z}_{22}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$, by the Chinese remainder theorem, we have that $\mathbb{Z}_{22}^*\cong \mathbb{Z}_2^*\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}^*\cong \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ which is cyclic.

The question is, why is $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^*\cong \mathbb{Z}_{10}$? Well since $10=2\cdot 5$ and there is a general result that says that  $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is cyclic if and only if $n=2,4,p^{r}, 2p^{r}$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

You can easily show this, write $n=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{m_i}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_n^*\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{m_1}}^*\times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_k
^{m_k}}^*$. Notice that $\mathbb{Z}^*_{2}=1, \mathbb{Z}^*_{4}= \mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_{p^{r}}^*=\mathbb{Z}_{(p-1)p^{r-1}}$, from this and again the Chinese remainder theorem, you can conclude the result.

Comment: Ah sorry, you accepted this, but I misread the question, I will give a new answer!